# How to popup a confirmation box on condition on ASPX page?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, ajax

I'have seen several tutorial/demos but can't solve my problem for my ASPX page(C#). 
I want popup a confirmation message box with Yes & No buttons on a button click event **but after checking a condition**.

After clicking the button it will check the condition like, ***if(a>b)***, if condition is true confirmation box will be poped up otherwise skip and no message will be poped up. 
After that If user click Yes button on confirmation message box, it will proceed further.

Please provide the code as I'm Beginner.

Comment: What did you attempt? It's straight forward.

Comment: Do you have any code showing what you're trying to work with? You could set the buttons onclick event to point at a js function. In the function check the condition and use confirm();

Comment: I've Two values in variable A & B. I want to check A should be lower than B and execute an **insert command** . When A is not lower than B, the message box should be popup and ask for confirmation to execute that insert command. If user click Yes, the command will execute and do nothing if "No" button clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a really simple example for a beginner using Bootstrap.Simple copy and paste the code below and it will work:

**Code behind(.cs file):**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblOutput.Text = String.Empty;
    bool showModal = true;

    if(showModal)
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myModal", "$('#myModal').modal('show');", true);
}

protected void Decision_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    lblOutput.Text = "User clicked - " + e.CommandArgument;
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="OK" OnClick="btnClick_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Would you like to continue?</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h3>Would you like to coninue?</h3>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnYes" runat="server" Text="Yes" OnCommand="Decision_Command" CommandArgument="Yes" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnNo" runat="server" Text="No" OnCommand="Decision_Command" CommandArgument="No" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image: Popup confirmation using Bootstrap]

Comment: Thanks finally I got what I want...but I've few problem. 
1. my page is not getting active after confirmation, it remains hidden
2. if I don't want to use "<script src>", so how can I hide "mymodal".

Comment: You must use <script> tags it's the only way to process javascript on the page.Google "how to close bootstrap modal popup"

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on the right track. `yes` and `no` aren't implemented by `confirm()` You have to switch to an alternative like [sweetalert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)

```js
var select = document.getElementById('c'),
    btn    = document.getElementById('check');

// Add click event
btn.onclick = function(){

   var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value; // I could also use Boolean(value); to convert it to boolean and not use quote for comparsion.
 
   // Checking if condition is true. If yes, then ask for user confirmation.
   if(value == '1'){
     
      console.log('condition is true; asking for confirmation');
     
      var ask = confirm('The condition is true, do you want to continue?');
      // if confirmed;
      if(ask){
         console.log('confirmed');
      // if denied/cancelled
      } else {
         console.log('cancelled');
      }
   }

}
```

```html
Condition:
<select id="c">
   <option value="1">true</option>
   <option value="0">false</option>
</select>
<button id="check">Check</button>
```

Comment: replace `value == '1'` with your own condition. I provided you with a minimal example to get you started with.

Comment: Under which tag i should write the following code
    Condition:
<select id="c">
   <option value="1">true</option>
   <option value="0">false</option>
</select>
<button id="check">Check</button>

Comment: I am not sure I if I caught your last comment. Could you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, as I beginner, I try to clarify. I have two file for an aspx page, one is code file(example.aspx.cs) & other is GUI file(example.aspx). I write your first code in example.aspx.cs. Now where should I write your HTML code in example.aspx